# How to extract a pair of sub-strings with certain patterns separated by any characters in a string using Python Reg?

Tags: python, regex, string

Need to get 2 sub-strings from strings. The two sub-strings are separated by multiple characters including special characters like colons and dollar signs, etc. The two sub-strings have their specific patterns respectively.

Background:

There are 3 strings showing sport events and their final results if the results exist. In each string, the sport event's name and its result are separated by irrelevant characters. Need to extract the event's name and its result if it exists. If the event has no result, nothing is extracted.

Following 3 strings are the examples:

```
String[0] = 'Boys 10&U Event 1 2.32WBC aRc$-MW 9O%Abd, dL 2.3SV Dd$-MW 10Tzos, edResult, Final 93.1AB-ED Boys 13&O Event 1 e&12d &12C, Ac&c AcResult, Final 1.5ED-cA'
```

From `String[0]`, need to get

`[('Boys 10&U Event 1', 'Result, Final 93.1'), ('Boys 13&O Event 1', 'Result, Final 1.5')]`

```
String[1] =  'Boys 7&U Event 2 2.3B Rd$-ac %d, a 2@Ac Dd$-MW '
```

From `String[1]`, nothing to extract as the event has no result.

```
String[2] = 'Boys 7&U Event 2 c3$ 13_E Boys 10&U Event 3 2.32WBC aRc$-MW 9O%Abd, dL 2.3SV Dd$-MW 10Tzos, edResult, Final 1.23AB-ED'
```

From `String[2]`, need to get

`('Boys 10&U Event 3', 'Result, Final 1.23') and totally ignore 'Boys 7&U Event 2'.`

I use the following code to process 3 strings above, with `s = String[0], String[1], String[2].`

```
re.findall(r'(Boys \d+&\[A-Z]\s\Event\s\d*).*?(Result, Final\s\d*\.\d{2})[A-Z]*', s)
```

The code works well on `String[0]` and `String[1]`, but doesn't work on `String[2]` as it extracts the first sport event's name and the 2nd sport event's result.

Could anyone help me create a code to extract the name and the result of sport event in each string? If a sport event has no corresponding result, the code needs to ignore this event.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your current regex works on either of the strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current regex has problems due to which it isn't even matching with any of your strings. For e.g. in your regex `Final\s\d*\.\d{2}` you have written `\d{2}` but in your first sample, you only have one digit in expected results, `Final 93.1` and `Final 1.5` due to which first string doesn't give a match.

Here is the regex you need to use for getting your desired matches,

```
(Boys\s+\S+\s+Event\s\d+)(?:(?!Boys).)*?(Result, Final\s\d*\.\d+)
```

**Regex explanation:**

- `(Boys` - Starts capture group then matches `Boys` literally
- `\s+\S+\s+` - Matches at least one white space then at least one non-whitespace then at least one white space
- `Event\s\d+)` - Matches `Event` literally then matches a whitespace then one or more digits
- `(?:(?!Boys).)*?` - This part matches any character zero or more except `Boys` due to which it selects the closest `Boys` string to the ending string.
- `(Result, Final\s\d*\.\d+)` - Starts second capture group then matches `Result, Final` literally then a white space then a decimal number where whole number part is optional

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LkWBkV/1)**

Sample Python code,

```
import re

arr = ['Boys 10&U Event 1 2.32WBC aRc$-MW 9O%Abd, dL 2.3SV Dd$-MW 10Tzos, edResult, Final 93.1AB-ED Boys 13&O Event 1 e&12d &12C, Ac&c AcResult, Final 1.5ED-cA', 'Boys 7&U Event 2 2.3B Rd$-ac %d, a 2@Ac Dd$-MW ','Boys 7&U Event 2 c3$ 13_E Boys 10&U Event 3 2.32WBC aRc$-MW 9O%Abd, dL 2.3SV Dd$-MW 10Tzos, edResult, Final 1.23AB-ED']

for s in arr:
 print(re.findall(r'(Boys\s+\S+\s+Event\s\d+)(?:(?!Boys).)*?(Result, Final\s\d*\.\d+)',s))
```

Prints,

```
[('Boys 10&U Event 1', 'Result, Final 93.1'), ('Boys 13&O Event 1', 'Result, Final 1.5')]
[]
[('Boys 10&U Event 3', 'Result, Final 1.23')]
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! You are the BEST! Your solution works! I missed one digit when I typed in the question. My bad. I will use your solution anyway and learn more about the ? in Regular Expression.

Comment: Glad I could help :) You can go over [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) to learn some basics on regex and this link also gives you references of some great sites for learning regex.

Comment: Thank you again for the valuable information which is truly what I need!